# TFS gate overrides auditing

Tags: continuous-integration

I believe I read there's a way but I can't seem to find it.

I want to see what check-ins and what users have overridden the gated build, or other policies. Where can I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tfs power tools has an alert explorer that you allows you to setup emails if a policy is overridden.

I believe it also allows you to setup a call to a webpage with the information.